# Skyrim - Crashed Hard disk lost all local saves, steam cloud backed up nothing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam-cloud

I've put many hours into skyrim but recently lost all my local save game files in my documents etc, to a Hard Drive crash.

I reinstalled Skyrim hoping that steam cloud had something I could salvage from in the cloud saves, but there is nothing at all.

Anyone have any idea why this would happen?

I've checked after re-installing steam and cloud save feature is enabled . Library > right click Skyrim > properties > Updates > enable cloud save.

I'm nearly positive Cloud Save would have been previously enabled because all my other games are using cloud save and I've never disabled this feature.

Btw - i know i know, i should have backed up my Documents via Drop box etc. actually this happened as a result of installing windows 8... It managed to corrupt my backup external Harddisk... don't ask! I tried recovery software this and that nothing worked : ( I lost a tonne of stuff...

Comment: If it was not enabled Before you crashed then nothing was saved.

Comment: It was enabled though i mentioned that above

Comment: Did you take a break from Skyrim? I played a lot after release, stopped for several months, had a disk crash, and there were no Cloud backups of my saves. My suspicion is that Skyrim didn't get Cloud compatibility until one of the updates sometime after the last time I'd played, so the feature didn't even exist. If you took a break too, that might be why.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yep i hadn't played in a few months so you might be right damn. Guess i'm starting a new character :) What did you do, get a save from nexus et al, or just start again?

Comment: I just started again. My new character ended up being better because I knew better what I was doing, and I had a better mod list for the same reason. (Aside, I can recommend "Alternate Start - Live Another Life" to skip the whole Helgen/dragon/Ulfric intro and experience Skyrim from a fresh perspective. It doesn't disable the main quest, just lets you start it later. I liked having my Mage start as a student at the university more than as a hapless civil war prisoner.)

Comment: Sounds good, I don't remember seeing that alternate Start option though hopefully i can at least start with that. Cheers for your help

Comment: It's a mod by one of the most respected TES modders around: [Alternate Start - Live Another Life](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/9557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you took enough of a break from Skyrim before losing the saves, they won't have been backed up in Steam Cloud. Skyrim didn't have Cloud support at launch, only adding it in one of the later updates – about the time that Steam Workshop support was added.

Comment: Well I ended up getting everything back. Turned out I randomly found a hidden folder called "found.000" which chkdisk had apparently moved from a 100GB folder "@@Backup" when i moved from a upgraded version of windows 8 to a fresh SSD install. 
The only reason I discovered the "found.000" folder is by using Hirens boot CD. windows 8 couldn't see the directory even with show hidden holders turned on.... That would explain why disk recovery tools etc, couldn't find the data it was never deleted just moved. whatever....

Anyway my documents, photos, steam saves all recovered.

Comment: Sweet, that's a stroke of luck.